# How to Mass Assignment laravel fillable

Tags: php, laravel

```
<form action="display" method="post">

<label>Details</label></br> 
<input type="radio" name="vishal" value="male">vishal</br>  
<input type="radio" name="vishal" value="female">male</br>  
<input type="radio" name="vishal" value="other">other</br>  

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xYj3n27EQNybQvY29mDrZxoYy3sGtbFTqfN8xeso">    

<label>Details</label></br> 
<input type="radio" name="rahul" value="male">rahul</br>    
<input type="radio" name="rahul" value="female">male</br>   
<input type="radio" name="rahul" value="other">other</br>   

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xYj3n27EQNybQvY29mDrZxoYy3sGtbFTqfN8xeso">    

<label>Details</label></br> 
<input type="radio" name="demo" value="male">demo</br>  
<input type="radio" name="demo" value="female">male</br>    
<input type="radio" name="demo" value="other">other</br>    

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xYj3n27EQNybQvY29mDrZxoYy3sGtbFTqfN8xeso">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

- **How can I insert without manually filling in each field?**
- I currently have the following **protected $fillable = ['gender','vishal','rahul', 'demo'];**
- But my fields are multiple **and I cant write manual fillable parameters for each field**
- How can I insert without **$fillable in to database?**

Comment: You need to assign `$fillable` as empty array like so. `protected $fillable = [];`

Comment: **It does not insert value** to the database protected $fillable =[];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution need to use

```
YourModel:: forceCreate($request->all());
```